# Using trained Azure Visual model in Java

Tags: java, azure, image-recognition

I am using Azure Visual Recognition in a Java Project. I am able to use the Visual recognition service (default) in my code. But I am trying to use the training key for the model that I created as a Project in Azure. Is there a possibility of passing the training key as a parameter in the Header for Azure? I have tried the following to pass it as a parameter in the header, but it doesn't make any difference to the results.

```
request.setHeader("Prediction-Key","my-key");
request.setHeader("Training-Key","my-key");
request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
```

Is there something I am missing in the code? I have seen the documentation for C# to use trained models, but not Java.

Comment: Hi,Vini. I'm not sure which azure vision service you 're using. Custom vision service ? ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Custom-Vision-Service/home)

Comment: Yes. Custom Vision service is the one I am using. I have found the solution for my problem. Thanks for your message...